# Samsung Note 4 power saving mode problem

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-4

I am using Samsung Note 4. When I turn to power saving mode I cannot get back to normal mode. I don't know what to do. Recently I've updated to the latest version. Can you please help me to switch it to its original settings.

Comment: Related but cant link them as they dont have an accepted answer.  https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/187352/how-to-solve-unfortunately-launcher-has-stopped-galaxy-note-4

Answer (score 0):

I use NOTE4 N910C. I notice the same issue (and many more) in MM 6.0.1. The workaround I use is to install Avast Battery Saver and other apps from Avast (for free). It is possible to define profiles (like "Night profile") and it reduce battery consumption dramatically. And wait for bug fixing from $amsung