# How to solve "Unfortunately, Launcher has stopped." Galaxy Note 4?

Tags: launcher, samsung-galaxy-note-4

I'm receiving this error after enabling ultra power saving mode:

> "Unfortunately, Launcher has stopped."

Its dialog only has the option "OK". Restarting doesn't work. Clearing cache partition through recovery doesn't work.

I can access settings by pulling down from the top of the screen but the settings menu is not complete; It only has Wi-Fi, Bluetooth, Airplane mode, Mobile networks, Location, Sound and Display entries.

My device is not rooted. It seems that the device is still on ultra power saving mode, even after clearing cache.

I have the option to factory reset through recovery but I prefer not loosing my data, if it's possible. What can I do?

Comment: Related: [Samsung Note 4 power saving mode problem](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/150493/12442)

Answer (score 0):

Go into [safe mode](https://support.t-mobile.com/docs/DOC-28897), this will filter out any third party app which could be causing problems.

**Here's how to enter safe mode**

1. Turn the device off.
2. Press and hold the Power and Volume down key.
3. Release the Power key when the Samsung logo appears but continue to hold the Volume down key until the device finishes restarting.
4. Safe mode will display in the bottom left corner of the screen.

When in safe mode, disable ultra power saving mode. You could also clear data for your launcher. To do that, go to settings>apps, in the menu, select 'show system apps'>touch wiz>storage>clear data.

If there are any third party apps that you suspect of misbehaving, you should uninstall them while in safe mode.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've booted into safe mode but I'm still getting the launcher error, and again, settings menu is not complete, so I can't access power saving setting or clear data. It seems that ultra power saving is still on in safe mode.

Comment: Firstly, the settings you are seeing is normal for u power saving. Those are the only settings i see on my phone when in UPS mode. When you pull down the notification bar, is there no 'notification' that said 'turn off ultra ps? That's what i have on my s5. I'm afraid your only option is a factory reset. Before you do that, see if removing your sd card fixes the issue

Comment: I see a notification about turning off safe mode, not ultra power saving mode. Isn't there any other workaround to solve it (like using adb etc)? Doing a factory reset just because of UPS is not what I expected ...

Comment: True, how did i not think of those other options? Maybe it's because i don't know much about it. The only thing i can suggest at this point is, as soon as it tells you that launcher has stopped, press ok and right away press on the three dots on the top right and press exit upsm. This is assuming that you have that split second before it crashes again. The other options I'll leave to someone else to answer